# Access denide on other root level directories with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, directory

I am trying to copy a file from a child directory of my root directory of the website to another root level directory

from 
    someDir\root\child1\child2\file.jpg
to
    SomeDir\testDir\file.jpg

but it gives me error
Access to the path 'C:\Users....' is denied.

Same code works just fine on production server, so I believe its some 
IIS environment variable but dont know which one.

I have full access on those directories with all my accounts and no error in path 
writing either...I am running IIS 7 & production server is IIS 6

Help???

Comment: IIS 7 is a LOT more restrictive in how it implements security than IIS 6.  How are you trying to copy the file?  Is it in code or via Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is: What user is your code actually executing under?

Specifically, what is the Application Pool running under?

Typically this is going to be Network Service, Local System, an App Pool Identity, or similar.  Rarely is it one of *your* accounts.  Verify that the identified user actually has the appropriate rights to the target directory

Comment: haaaa...it worked... thanks for the accounts heads up..
I went to pool & changed the authentication to my own.. works fine now.
Thank you. I appreciate the help :)